# WPF DatePicker Icon Size

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` like this:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="43" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}"/>
```

The problem is, that increasing the font size of the date picker doesn't resize the icon and it remains small.

[image]

I've searched but couldn't find a proper way to only resize the icon, or maybe this is not the proper way of enlarging the whold picker

Comment: Try leaving the font size at the default and giving it a LayoutTransform (or maybe it should be the RenderTransform -- try both; I'm on my phone): `<DatePicker ...etc... RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" /><LayoutTransform><ScaleTransform ScaleX="4" ScaleY="4" /></LayoutTransform></DatePicker>` This may scale the icon by interpolation, which would be ugly, but give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks. It does the job. Need to adjust the scales to match the end width and height, but at least it's something

Comment: How did you enlarge the textbox of the datepicker, I've searched many links but still no answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to put the DatePicker into a Viewbox and adjust the size of the Viewbox. So borrowing from your example, you might have

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150">
    <DatePicker CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

where increasing/decreasing the Viewbox.Width parameter will allow you to adjust the size of the DatePicker.

Answer (score 6):

For people who are not satisfied with the simple answers from Michael Repucci there is a "cleaner" alternative solution to my taste which allows you to surround only the icon by a viewbox.
You can right click on the element you want to modify on the Design panel of an xaml file and click on "modify model". This will take you to the xaml code of the element. Then you have to locate the part you want to modify. Here I have surrounded only the Button that contains the icon with a ViewBox and not the whole control.
The part in question is almost at the bottom. I put some line feeds to make it more visible.

[image: Default style vs New style]

```
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerIconResizingStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTodayHighlighted" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedDateFormat" Value="Short"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,0" StartPoint=".5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBrush" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="DropDownButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Grid Background="#11FFFFFF" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="18" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border x:Name="Highlight" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="0,0,1,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="Background" Background="#FF1F3B53" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" CornerRadius=".5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundGradient" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#BF000000" CornerRadius=".5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Opacity="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF494949"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                            <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Data="M11.426758,8.4305077 L11.749023,8.4305077 L11.749023,16.331387 L10.674805,16.331387 L10.674805,10.299648 L9.0742188,11.298672 L9.0742188,10.294277 C9.4788408,10.090176 9.9094238,9.8090878 10.365967,9.4510155 C10.82251,9.0929432 11.176106,8.7527733 11.426758,8.4305077 z M14.65086,8.4305077 L18.566387,8.4305077 L18.566387,9.3435936 L15.671368,9.3435936 L15.671368,11.255703 C15.936341,11.058764 16.27293,10.960293 16.681133,10.960293 C17.411602,10.960293 17.969301,11.178717 18.354229,11.615566 C18.739157,12.052416 18.931622,12.673672 18.931622,13.479336 C18.931622,15.452317 18.052553,16.438808 16.294415,16.438808 C15.560365,16.438808 14.951641,16.234707 14.468243,15.826504 L14.881817,14.929531 C15.368796,15.326992 15.837872,15.525723 16.289043,15.525723 C17.298809,15.525723 17.803692,14.895514 17.803692,13.635098 C17.803692,12.460618 17.305971,11.873379 16.310528,11.873379 C15.83071,11.873379 15.399232,12.079271 15.016094,12.491055 L14.65086,12.238613 z" Fill="#FF2F2F2F" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,3,4,3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisual" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#B2FFFFFF" CornerRadius="0,0,.5,.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!-- This ViewBox allows to resize the icon automatically to fill the full height of the DatePicker -->
                            <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Button x:Name="PART_Button"  Focusable="False" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  Template="{StaticResource DropDownButtonTemplate}" />
                            </Viewbox>

                            <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#A5FFFFFF" Height="18" Margin="3,0,3,0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="19"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="PART_TextBox" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I hope this answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution that worked was to put only the calendar button inside a viewbox.

[image]

```
<DatePicker...>
 
  <DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Viewbox>
             <ContentPresenter/>
           </Viewbox>
         </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.Resources>
 
</DatePicker>
```